# Tomcat7 host app to another folder

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7

I want to host my webapp `test.war` file like following
webapp path should be `/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/testapps/testfolder/test.war` so I can access it like `localhost/testapps/testfolder/test` How can I achive this.?

Answer (score 0):

You can define [Virtual Hosts](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/virtual-hosting-howto.html) and set the `appBase` to your required path. The default appBase ist defined in `/conf/server.xml`.